# Run Genymotion Android Emulator in a Santoku (Lubuntu) VM

Tags: virtualbox, android, lubuntu

I have a Lubunut-VM (updated with Santoku packages) running on a Windows 10 host in VirtualBox. I installed VirtualBox and Genymotion in my VM.

I had to install libstdc++6 to get Genymotion to work.

When starting the Virtual Android Device using Genymotion I get the following error message:(I am not allowed to embedd images in my posts...)

[image: ErrorGenymotion]

If I start the Android VM in VirtualBox I get the following error:

[image: ErrorVB]

And here the logs:

```
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Virtual device configured
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Virtualization engine configured
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "GN6P - 7.0.0 - API 24 - 01")
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Trying to log in as "JBDH"
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/login/" )
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Virtual Machine status: off
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Start the device...
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "set", "GN6P - 7.0.0 - API 24 - 01", "androvm_ip_management")
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("modifyvm", "GN6P - 7.0.0 - API 24 - 01", "--nic1", "hostonly")
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("modifyvm", "GN6P - 7.0.0 - API 24 - 01", "--hostonlyadapter1", "vboxnet0")
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("modifyvm", "GN6P - 7.0.0 - API 24 - 01", "--nictype1", "virtio")
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("modifyvm", "GN6P - 7.0.0 - API 24 - 01", "--cableconnected1", "on")
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "set", "GN6P - 7.0.0 - API 24 - 01", "genymotion_player_version", "1")
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "set", "GN6P - 7.0.0 - API 24 - 01", "genymotion_vm_name", "GN6P - 7.0.0 - API 24 - 01")
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "GN6P - 7.0.0 - API 24 - 01")
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
Apr 13 11:35:36 [Genymotion Player] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("startvm", "GN6P - 7.0.0 - API 24 - 01", "--type", "headless")
Apr 13 11:35:37 [Genymotion Player] [debug] "User JBDH (jonas.ber@gmx.de) logged on Hub"
Apr 13 11:35:37 [Genymotion Player] [debug] Pending calls: 0
Apr 13 11:35:37 [Genymotion Player] [debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/" )
Apr 13 11:35:37 [Genymotion Player] [warning] Activation failed. Error: 9 - "HTTP code 403: Activation failed: license have never been registered Error downloading https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/ - server replied: FORBIDDEN"
Apr 13 11:35:37 [Genymotion Player] [critical] [VBox] Return code: 1
Apr 13 11:35:37 [Genymotion Player] [critical] [VBox] Unable to start virtual device: "GN6P - 7.0.0 - API 24 - 01"
Apr 13 11:35:37 [Genymotion Player] [critical] [VBox] Try to launch virtual device from VirtualBox to check the issue.
Apr 13 11:35:37 [Genymotion Player] [critical] Unable to start virtual device
```

The problem should be VT-X support? But I enabled it in the VirtualBox settings of the Lubuntu-VM. Is there a possibility to get this to work? Or is this simply not possible?

Thank you for your help!